# Sorting SQL results by date on the CLIENT instead of in the QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

suppose I have some table that is tracking a users weight over time.

```
CREATE TABLE `userWeights` (
  `weight_id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int,
  `weight` float,
  `date_created` timestamp
);
```

The obvious use-case here is some REST endpoint getWeights(user_id) and then display it as a graph on the UI. 
The standard query I would write would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM userWeights WHERE user_id=user_id ORDER BY date_created ASC
```

but seeing as as we're sorting by date, business logic that would never change for this use-case, could the sorting computational load be outsourced to the client's device and thus improve the performance of the SQL query? would this be a mostly insignificant improvement for, say, a table of 1000 users where we store 6 months of daily weight measurements?

```
SELECT * FROM userWeights WHERE user_id=user_id
results.sort(date_created, ASCENDING); //e.g. code on android device
```

EDIT: I ask because many cloud function/cloud database hosts charge based on computation time per invocation.

Comment: As long as you can't sort it better or with other mens, this would cost you the same. even the number of rows is small

Answer (score 0):

In general, sorting is going to be faster on the database server than in the client application.

In your two scenarios, the amount of data being passed between the database and the client is the same.  The only difference is the overhead for sorting.

Normally, my recommendation is to do the sorting on the more powerful system, closer to the data.  However, if you have a good reasons -- and cost considerations are a good reason -- and sorting on the client side fits your application performance requirements, then you can definitely consider doing that processing client-side.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the actual sorting of the data client-side vs. server-side is negligible - but usually faster closer to the data (doing it on the database server).

However, there are some other things to consider when thinking of where to put the sorting:

1. Maintainability - If you put the logic client-side, then any new client you add will have to implement the sorting logic as well. So if you have a web app, iOS app and Android app, you will have to make sure to implement the sort in all three applications to get a consistent UX. If you want to change the sort across all apps, you now have to remember to do it in three places, whereas if the logic was in a shared API or DB then you can make the change in one place.
2. Affordability- Like you said, cloud providers can charge for computation time. If that is a serious concern, you could move the sorting client-side but like I said before, the future maintainability will take a hit which will cost you developer time and therefore dollars in the future.

I would recommend figuring out how import maintainability is to you vs. affordability, and if moving the sorting client-side really would help affordability in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

KISS.

Adding an `ORDER BY` to the query is simple and hard to screw up.

Adding sorting to the client takes more keystrokes and is more error-prone.

Furthermore, it is possible to eat-your-cake without even paying for it!  The sort can be "free":

```
CREATE TABLE `userWeights` (
  `user_id` int,
  `weight` float,
  `date_created` timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, date_created)
);
```

You still need the `ORDER BY` clause on the `SELECT`, but notice that it will take *zero* effort on *either* the server or the client.

The way you had the table definition, it had to scan the entire table to find the rows for the requested `user_id`; this change avoids that, too.  Also, this saves space of the useless `weight_id`.

My suggestion has one problem:  You can't record two different weights taken in the same second.  (That seems like a bug to even try!)

Cost savings...

- The Optimizer will not charge anything for discovering that the data is already sorted.  (Above)
- Don't say `SELECT *`, that returns all the columns; you need only two:  `SELECT date_created, weight`.

Syntax problem:  `WHERE user_id=user_id` -- One of those needs to be the parameter coming in.  Else, it is equivalent to "TRUE".